# Calling findViewById from custom view returns null

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a custom class that is supposed to display two images in a certain way. Here are some selected parts of my code:

My XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <com.kupol24.app.presentation.view.customViews.MyImageLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pattern"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/start_pattern"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/start_logo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </com.kupol24.app.presentation.view.customViews.MyImageLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the class itself:

```
public class MyImageLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private ImageView patternImage, logoImage;
    private Bitmap pattern, logo;

    public MyImageLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        patternImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pattern);
        logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

        pattern = ((BitmapDrawable) patternImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        logo = ((BitmapDrawable) logoImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        pattern = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pattern, patternDiameter, patternDiameter, false);
        logo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(logo, logoDiameter, logoDiameter, false);
    }
}
```

The problem I get is that the findViewById returns null, instead of giving me the ImageView. How would I solve this issue? Thank you

Comment: Pass your Viwe in MyImageLayout() constructor

Comment: and use patternImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pattern);

Comment: It is recommended to use onFinishInflate() method to initialize subviews.

Comment: Those views don't exist until `onFinishInflate()` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem I get is that the findViewById returns null, instead of
>   giving me the ImageView. How would I solve this issue?

you don't have any assurance that the children of your custom layout have been added. ViewGroup has the [onFinishInflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate()) callback, which, as the documentations states, it is called as the last phase of inflation, after all child views have been added. Override this callback, and move your `findViewById` calls in there